# Yii framework: access rules not working properly

Tags: frameworks, yii

I have problem with access control. I have **rule:**

```
array('deny', 
    'actions'=>array('index'),
    'expression'=>'Yii::app()->user->isRegistered()',
    'deniedCallback' => array(
        $this->render('//site/info',array(
            'message'=>'You must activate your account.'
        )
    ),Yii::app()->end()), 
),
```

**function:**

```
public function isRegistered()
{
    return (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) ? FALSE : $this->level == 1;
}
```

If I login as admin and i have level 3, isRegistered() return false, but deniedCalback runs.

How to change this to run callback only when expression is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the callback as [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). The way you wrote it, it will always execute the code you have in that array. You should better write a dedicated method in the controller.

```
array('deny', 
    'actions'=>array('index'),
    'expression'=>'Yii::app()->user->isRegistered()',
    'deniedCallback' => array($this, 'accessDenied'),  
),

// ...

public function accessDenied()
{
    $this->render('//site/info', array(
        'message' => 'You must activate your account.'
    ));
    Yii::app()->end(); // not really neccessary
}
```